# focusout not working jquery

Tags: jquery, html, focusout

I am having some issues with focusout. I want an alert when an input box is selected and I click out of the inputbox. However, after I click it and click out of it, I do not get an alert. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#val1").focusout(function(){
            alert('focusout');
        });
    });
</script>


<p><label>Value: </label><input id="val1" type="text" placeholder="example: val"></p>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works after copied your code into [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/w1e3yhof/). I also added focusin function as well. So you can do some comparison. [focusout](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_focusout.asp) with [focusin](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_focusin.asp)

```
    $("#val1").focusout(function(){
        alert('focusout');
    });
    $("#val1").focusin(function(){
        alert('focusin');
    });
```

Comment: You don't need to select the element again. Why not use method chain?

Answer (score 6):

.focusout() only works when you click on another focusable element.  The problem, which I'm trying to sort through as well, is what happens when you click right outside of the input box.  The input no longer has focus, but the focusout event is not triggered.

I would appreciate anyone's thoughts on this!!